# Merging a folder of 34,000 images in Photoshop

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, imagemagick

I have a folder of 34,000 images (all the exact same size) and I would like to layer them all on top of each other, doing something equivalent to Photoshop's "Darker Color" layer blending mode.

I don't think actions will work, as those are meant to operate a given action on a batch of images. I need something along the lines of "File > scripts > load files into a stack". The problem is if I try to do that on the entire folder Photoshop hangs.

Is there some kind of way to make this into a custom action? If it's possible it would likely help, since I could flatten and merge the layers on each iteration to avoid an unwieldy file with 34,000 layers.

I'm also open to using Imagemagick if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish my goal using that...

Comment: Well, hanging is not a surprise there. Why the need to overlay/merge 34000 images?

Comment: What do you expect to see from combining 34,000 images? Can you perform the operation in batches? "_Photoshop hangs_" - how long did you give it to thing about life? (it may eventually work, but 34,000 is a **big** number)

Comment: "_I'm also open to using Imagemagick if anyone has any ideas on how to accomplish my goal using that_" - can you clarify what exactly you're trying to achieve? Does the [Mathematical Compose Methods](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#math) documentation give you anything useful?

Comment: Are you attempting image stacking for astrophotography? See https://astrobackyard.com/tutorials/stack-exposures/ and suggestion for programs specifically for that.

Comment: I don't see how my reason for this need is pertinent, but since you're all curious, this is for reverse engineering an obsolete piece of software. I'll leave it at that ;-)

Comment: Provide 7-10 images and the expected result and I'll try and give you a good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, inspired by the other answer which partially worked but had a few bugs I wrote my own Python implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import subprocess

dir = [path to dir with all of the images]
targetdir = [path to target dir]
mylist = os.listdir(dir)

max = 34867
i = 0

while i <= 34867:
    try:
        cmd = ['convert', targetdir+'composite'+str(i)+'.png', dir+mylist[i] ,'-compose','darken','-composite',targetdir+'composite'+str(i+1)+'.png']
        subprocess.call(cmd, shell=False)
        print(i)
        os.remove(targetdir+'composite'+str(i)+'.png')
        i = i+1
    except:
        i = i-1
        print("hmm "+dir+mylist[i]+" didn't work")
```

You just have to take the first file from the sequence, name it "composite0.png" and put it in the target dir. Then let it rip, and watch the numbers tick by in stdout. Getting Imagemagick errors now and then that I need to sort out, so for now just adding an exception until I can get to the bottom of those.

Comment: Just a note that my exception didn't handle the errors in question (I think likely because the error is part of the subprocess) but I figured out why they were happening (there were some hidden files it was trying to use) so it worked anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine you are going to have a hard time over-coming the issues you are experiencing with Photoshop hanging due to the number of files involved.

However, since you stated you are open to using Imagemagick.

Here is a Python script that ackomplishes this task in three steps.

1. Divide the Task: Instead of processing all the images at once, group the images in chunks. For example, process 100 images at a time.
2. Blend the Chunked Images: Use ImageMagick to blend each chunk and produce a resulting image.
3. Blend the Resultant Images: After all chunks are processed, blend
   the resultant images together.

```
import os
import subprocess

IMAGE_FOLDER = '/path/to/images'  # Replace with your images path
CHUNK_SIZE = 100
OUTPUT_FOLDER = '/path/to/output'  # Replace with your desired output path

images = sorted(os.listdir(IMAGE_FOLDER))

chunk_images = [images[i:i + CHUNK_SIZE] for i in range(0, len(images), CHUNK_SIZE)]
resultant_images = []

for idx, chunk in enumerate(chunk_images):
    first_image = chunk[0]
    command = f'convert {os.path.join(IMAGE_FOLDER, first_image)}'

    for image in chunk[1:]:
        command += f' {os.path.join(IMAGE_FOLDER, image)} -compose darken -composite'

    output_image = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, f'result_{idx}.png')
    command += f' {output_image}'
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
    resultant_images.append(output_image)

# Now blend the resultant images together
command = f'convert {resultant_images[0]}'

for image in resultant_images[1:]:
    command += f' {image} -compose darken -composite'

final_output_image = os.path.join(OUTPUT_FOLDER, 'final_result.png')
command += f' {final_output_image}'
subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```

You will need ImageMagick installed and the convert command accessible from the terminal and you will need to replace the paths to suit your local setup.

Comment: This is a great approach! I had been trying to do it all in the CLI with Imagemagick, but of course handling it via Python makes way more sense. Your script partially worked, but threw a few errors: ```"convert: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/746." "convert: image sequence is required `-composite' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageList/8040." and "convert: TooManyExceptions (exception processing is suspended) @ warning/exception.c/ThrowException/1049."``` It made the first stage composites, but didn't combine them all. It also missed a few images.